# SAS 9.2 Integration with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, database, sas

I'm trying to find out the different ways I can use to connect to a SAS DB using .Net.  Could you please tell me the best ways to connect to a SAS DB using .Net?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Can we execute SAS queries using ADO.net?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for more complete integration than just querying a table then it is possible if you have SAS Integration Technologies licensed:

http://support.sas.com/rnd/itech/doc9/overview/index.html

Comment: Actually this is what we ended up doing.  The client had a license, so we got the DLLs and managed to interact using the DLLs.  Definitely made out jobs much easier.

Comment: Good to know and I'm glad it worked out.  Thanks for the written confirmation =)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this full reference on SAS 9.2 and OLEDB style interaction:

[SAS 9.2 Providers for OLE DB Cookbook](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/oledbpr/59558/PDF/default/oledbpr.pdf)

To know more about ADO.NET OLEDB:

[ADO.NET OLEDB](http://vb.net-informations.com/ado.net-dataproviders/ado.net-oledbconnection.htm)

Comment: Can we execute SAS queries using ADO.NET?